# use boolean with visible, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there a better way to do use a use a boolean with visible? I'm setting up animations that have conditions for visibility, and I don't want to use something that performs poorly.

This animation blinks 30 times and stops. It works without error, but takes a moment to load. I would like to learn other ways of using visibility with conditionals.

This is what I used 'waits before playing'

```
if(condition=5){
box.visible = !box.visible;
```

This works fine 'no pause'

```
if(condition<6){
box.visible = !box.visible;
```

Complete code that's buggy

```
var timz:Timer = new Timer(100,30);
timz.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, doIt);
var condition:Number = 5;
function doIt(event:TimerEvent):void{
trace("fire!");
if(condition=5){
box.visible = !box.visible;
}
}
timz.start();
```

---

This works

```
if(condition==5){
box.visible = !box.visible;
```

This is the best 'nice tween effect'

```
var timz:Timer = new Timer(500,30);
timz.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, doIt);
var condition:Number = 5;
function doIt(event:TimerEvent):void{
trace("fire!");
if(condition==5){
//box.visible = !box.visible;
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
var myTweenAlpha:Tween = new Tween(box, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 0, 1, 1, true);
}
}
timz.start();
```

Comment: The time it takes to load has hardly anything to do with the use of boolean. You might however want to change "if(condition=5)" to "if(condition==5)".

Comment: @bitc. That's quicker. I make an update, post if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning 5 to condition in the conditional, is that intentional?

You could use the .alpha property to provide more subtle animations, but I figure the best solution would be to just use a tween engine. TweenLite (http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/) has a great shorthand syntax for these kind of animations.

Comment: @dario, I'm testing the syntax. My coding is sloppy, and I wanted to explore the best way of coding these. I tried a tweening method as you were posting.